# Redirected to wrong url

Tags: django, url, django-urls

I have 2 urls which are kind of similar,

```
path('account/', views.register_login, name='register_login'), 
path('account/<slug:user_slug>/', views.home, name='account'),
```

When I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/account/

I get redirected to the url with name account instead of to the one with name register_login.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
Thank you so much for your answer, but turns out the issue was caused because of a slug on another application my friend implemented and I was unaware off.

I'm working on a core app so I don't use an appname, yet he's supposed to do so. We misunderstood each other and neither of us named our respective application hahahaha. So I was being redirected to his urls and his views...

Comment: Can you show the `views.register_login`. If you implement logic to redirect you, then of course that is not that odd.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but turns out the issue was caused because of a slug on another application my friend implemented and I was unaware off.

I'm working on a core app so I don't use an appname, yet he's supposed to do so. We misunderstood each other and neither of us named our respective application hahahaha. So I was being redirected to his urls and his views...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much everyone for your answer, but it turns out the issue was caused because of a slug on another application my friend implemented and I was unaware off.

I'm working on a core app so we said I wouldn't use an appname, yet he was supposed to do so. We misunderstood each other and neither of us named our respective application hahahaha. So I was being redirected to his urls and his views...